# Problemas con datatables en django

Tags: html, python, css, django, datatables

Tengo el siguiente problema con el cual necesito ayuda, pues no soy tan experimentado usando **datatables** en **Django**.

Cuando genero la siguiente tabla con **datatables** queda de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que la Bala 2 es una segunda tabla que genero mediante un ciclo anidado donde existen 2 Balas (pueden existir más), pero necesito que la segunda tabla aparezca al lado de la primera (de forma horizontal, no vertical). Además, cuando intento generar el excel, este me coge los datos de la primera tabla y no de la segunda.

Agradecería encarecidamente que me ayudaran ya que llevo varios días intentando y no logro avanzar en el proyecto!

Adjunto el código:

```
        {% for x in Bala %} 
            <div>
                <table class="table-sm" id="data">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 50px;"></th> 
                            <th style="width: 80px;"></th> 
                            <th style="width: 80px;">{{ x.1 }}</th>
                            <th style="width: 80px;"></th> 
                            <th style="width: 80px;"></th>          
                        </tr>                     
                    </thead>
                    <tbody >
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dia</th> 
                            <th>Porciento</th> 
                            <th>Litros</th>
                            <th>Gasto</th> 
                            <th>Entrada</th>            
                        </tr>
                        {% for c in x %}                      
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ c.fecha | date:"d" }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.porciento }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.litros }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.gasto }}</td>
                                <td>{{ c.entrada }}</td>      
                            </tr> 
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>                
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema se resuelve mostrando las tablas una al lado de la otra. Para esto podemos usar **css**.
Hay varias formas de resolver esto, una es usando `inline-block`.
Tu código fuente prácticamente no cambia.

```
    <div class="contenedor">
    {% for x in Bala %} 
        <div class="contenido">
            <table class="table-sm" id="data">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 50px;"></th> 
                        <th style="width: 80px;"></th> 
                        <th style="width: 80px;">{{ x.1 }}</th>
                        <th style="width: 80px;"></th> 
                        <th style="width: 80px;"></th>          
                    </tr>                     
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dia</th> 
                        <th>Porciento</th> 
                        <th>Litros</th>
                        <th>Gasto</th> 
                        <th>Entrada</th>            
                    </tr>
                    {% for c in x %}                      
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ c.fecha | date:"d" }}</td>
                            <td>{{ c.porciento }}</td>
                            <td>{{ c.litros }}</td>
                            <td>{{ c.gasto }}</td>
                            <td>{{ c.entrada }}</td>      
                        </tr> 
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>                
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Agregué un `div`, que engloba al `for`, con un nuevo estilo `contenedor`. A su vez el `div` dentro del `for` ahora tiene un estilo `contenido`, el cual tendrá el `inline-block` antes mencionado.

Los dos nuevos estilos son:

```
.contenedor {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.contenido {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

El estilo `contenido`, en su propiedad `display` tiene el valor `inline-block` que muestra las tablas lado a lado. Los `border` son para ver qué abarca cada `div` y pueden eliminarse (especialmente el borde rojo).
Hay otras formas de resolver este problema con **css**, te recomiendo la lectura del siguiente [artículo](https://dev.to/dawnind/3-ways-to-display-two-divs-side-by-side-3d8b)

Comment: Muy Buenas y gracias por su respuesta! la verdad es que si se pone la 2da tabla como quiero mediante su respuesta, sin embargo continua quedándose fuera la 2da tabla cuando genero el archivo en excel.

Comment: Ahí ya no te puedo ayudar. Tendrías que hacer otra pregunta pidiendo ayuda con la exportación a excel, donde conste cuál es la librería y procedimiento que ponés en práctica para exportar. Si la respuesta te ayudó con respecto a las tablas marcala como aceptada, como una forma de indicarle a otros usuarios que esta es la forma de resolver el problema planteado.